# How to expire JWT if a new one is generated

Tags: php, authentication, jwt

I am totally new in **JWT implementation** and an issue came up.

I have built a user login authentication with **JWT** in php. On user login, if user's credentials are valid then response of login API is a token which is stored as a **cookie** and instead of having `$_SESSION` variables, I get user's data by making an API call to decode token and retrieve user's data on every page of web application.

If user wants to update his personal details (name, e-mail etc) I want to **generate a new JWT** based on new details and to force previous one to expire or somehow make it invalid. So, in future API calls previous token must be invalid.
I thought of storing tokens on database but this is not right I suppose.

How can I make it works?

Comment: Follow this reference link https://medium.com/studioarmix/expiring-jwts-with-refresh-tokens-cf54057fe727

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Stateless authentication** (in this case JWT) stores the user session data on the client side (browser).

The data is signed by the key of IdP to ensure the integrity and authority of the session data.
Since the user session is stored on the **client side**, the server only have the capability to verify its validity by checking whether the payload and the signature match.

One of the disadvantages is that you cannot revoke the session anytime: since the user session is stored at client side, the server does not have any rights to delete the session.

• **What you can do:**

You can remove the stored JWT on the client and put this in a db blacklist and check everytime someone calls the APIs

Answer (score 2):

You cannot without making the api stateful.
So either you store a reference to the JWT in your database and delete it or you could blacklist the revoked tokens and check on authorization if the token was blacklisted and therefore is revoked.

Comment: Is there anyway to avoid a database set up?Such as somehow set a past expiration time on old cookie?

Comment: Then you just assume that the client/user will not use that token anymore.
So it makes no diffrence to deleting the cookie.
If you really want to avoid that this specific token can be used again you have to somehow introduce a state (e.g. database).

Answer (score 1):

You can do two things:

First delete the old JWT token and insert new one.

Or create an field (is_expired) in database to check the status of token and default should be false so when you create new one, it marked to true and the old one must change with false value.